# Ansible compare between two files on remote server

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to compare a file in two remote servers using ansible.

```
Server A: /var/tmp/text1.txt
Server B: /var/tmp/text1.txt
```

I would like to check if the two files are the same content.

Answer (score 4):

Compute a checksum of both files and then compare the checksum.  Assuming that we have two hosts in our inventory named `host0` and `host1`, something like this would work:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - command: sha256sum /var/tmp/text1.txt
      register: cksum

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: hostvars.host0.cksum.stdout == hostvars.host1.cksum.stdout
```

Comment: oh is it possible to implement for multiple hosts more than 2 ?

Comment: Sure. The logic would be a little different, but would be possible.

Comment: one more q, is it possible to grep certain string and checksum on that.

Comment: Ansible can run arbitrary commands and capture the output. You can do pretty much anything you want. If you have specific questions about how to accomplish something like that, you probably want to open a new question on that topic.